# phpexcel export to excel with image

Tags: php, mysql, image, excel

I have a table in my Database containing the data of many items with the name of its image.

From that table I want to display each item data with its image. This is the code I use to display it in PHP:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th style="border-width:medium;" rowspan="2">CODE</th>
    <th style="border:medium;" rowspan="2">CLR</th>
    <th style="border-width:medium;" rowspan="2">IMAGE</th>
    <th style="border-width:medium;" rowspan="2">DESCRIPTION</th>
    <th style="border-width:medium;" rowspan="2">QTY.</th>
    <th style="border-width:medium;" rowspan="2">PRICE</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($list as $data){?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$data->code_caption?></td>
    <td style="text-align:center"><?=$data->color?></td>
    <td style="width:135px; height:135px; text-align:center;">
    <img src="<?=base_url().'media/img/gallery/items/'.$data->image?>TH.jpg" style="margin:5px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;" />
    </td>
    <td><?=$data->desc?></td>
    <td style="text-align:center"><?=$data->qty?></td>
    <td style="text-align:right"><?=$data->price?></td>
  </tr>
<?php }?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to export the data to an Excel formatted file so it looks like what I display on my PHP page.

Can it be done?

I have tried to use the Excel header but the image becomes a link, it's not the complete image being embedded.

And I also saw the PHPexcel library, but I cannot find a way to write the loop with the image.

Any solution for my problem will be very helpful.

Comment: It can be done quite easily in PHPExcel, doesn't any of the documentation or examples help at all?

Comment: I have seen the document but i cannot find where the loop for image. I just found for 1 image(for logo or somethings alike) and data loping, could you give me the link? maybe i was missing that one when I check the documentation.

Comment: A loop for image is no different to doing one image, except that you just write a loop to do each of those images in turn

Comment: Could you give me the example code for my problem..??

Comment: @MarkBaker so you mean I need to make 
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing(); 
...
...
code trough the loop to?
i'm still trying and working in this case to.

Comment: Yes, you do; in each iteration of the loop you need to set the image that you need for that row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for Helping me I have found the answer for my own question.

```
    <?php

    $rowNumber = 12;
    foreach($list as $data){
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$rowNumber, $data->code_caption)
->setCellValue('B'.$rowNumber, $data->color);

if(file_exists('./media/img/gallery/items/'.$data->image.'TH.jpg'))
{
    $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
    $objDrawing->setPath('./media/img/gallery/items/'.$data->image.'TH.jpg');
    $objDrawing->setCoordinates('C'.$rowNumber);
    $objDrawing->setWorksheet($this->excel->getActiveSheet());
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($rowNumber)->setRowHeight(120);
}
else
{
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowNumber, '');
}

$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowNumber, $data->desc);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowNumber, $data->$d_met);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowNumber, $data->$w_met);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowNumber, $data->$h_met);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowNumber, $data->qty);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowNumber,$data->$cur_dat);           
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowNumber,$data->$total_price);
$rowNumber++;
    }?>
```