# Is it possible to export html table with an image to a spreadsheet

Tags: jquery

I used CSV for export, but image and style not exporting

```
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
 $("#tbContainer").tableToCSV();
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829324/phpexcel-export-to-excel-with-image

Comment: I don't think you can save images in a CSV file unless it supports Base64 encoding. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333522/how-can-i-include-image-into-csv